# Compass widget for MapActivity (Android)

Tags: android, android-maps

Id like to use the blue compass needle we all know from the Gmaps app.

- Is there a widget available I just
  have to turn on?
- If not, could you provide me
  Tutorials or the name of classes I
  should take a look at?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compass widget for MapActivity (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246848/compass-widget-for-mapactivity-android)

Comment: Yes, that was made by accident. I just closed it. There was one answer from Brian Mansell: Check out the Compass API Demo provided by Google on Android's site: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Compass.html

Comment: I ended up implementing the solution of CommonsWare (Blue dot + accuracy, but no compass) because that was the fastest way. I later read the answer from Brian (see comment above). His solution has a compass, but I didn't test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a widget available I just have to turn on?

Add `MyLocationOverlay` to your map, and call `enableCompass()` in `onResume()` and `disableCompass()` in `onPause()`. [Here is a project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk/) demonstrating this.

Comment: Oh ok, well thats a compass needle. But not the one from the gmaps app which indicates "My Location" at the same time. Thanks though

Comment: Oh, I just see. There is a "myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();" also. Thanks!

Comment: @OneWorld: Sorry, you only mentioned the compass in your question.

Comment: BUT, it's just a blue dot. Not a compass needle ;(. Probably wasnt a feature back in Android 1.5

Comment: The compass doesn't seem to be displayed within an emulator, I've yet to try it on a device.

Comment: @DriKu: There is no compass in the emulator. It does appear on a device.

Comment: Why does the compass needs to be enabled en disabled?

Comment: @Vincent: It uses the magnetic flux sensor, and so we need to tell Android when we no longer need that sensor, so it can unregister the listener and power down the sensor.