# Android google Maps How compass Works

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-markers, android-maps

I Completed coding of compass in google maps successfully with an example.

Now i just want to know is that

1. How do compass work in google maps (Each and every android device supports it).
2. Does it needs any sensors in the phone
3. From which Level of API levels it works

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this example: [Here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk/)

Also refer [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246842/compass-widget-for-mapactivity-android) for more information.